# If two identical balls were dropped from the same height, but one of them was given a push to the side also, which would hit the ground first and why?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, free-fall

I was wondering if two identical balls were dropped from say, 10 meters, but one of them was given a push to the side whilst dropped, which would hit the ground first and why? Would the ball that was pushed land later?

Comment: This is a great experiment to try.

Comment: Does the sideways push affect the downward speed?

Comment: no. Just a straight sideways push. Could you please explain the physics behind it too if you can answer.

Comment: I tried it and they both hit the ground on the same time. But, how does a bullet from a gun take so long to fall down.

Comment: If you shoot a bullet, why doesn't it just fall on the floor after like 1 second. How does it continue for miles?

Comment: How long would it take a bullet to fall to the ground if you just dropped it?  How long does it take a bullet to travel a long horizontal distance when you fire it?  Clue: when a bullet hits something it tends to make a mess of it, so I am guessing it is travelling very fast.

Answer (score 2):

The forces acting on the two balls are that  of gravity, and that of air resistance.

Ignoring the curvature of the planet, and possible difference in air resistance , the balls would fall at the same time, for example on the moon.

As the ball shifted to the right travels a longer path in the air, the air density for the vertical component may be changing for that  path , the air resistance force may have an effect  it with respect to the first one .The plot in [this answer](https://www.quora.com/After-a-bullet-leaves-a-gun-barrel-square-to-the-ground-does-it-drop-at-the-same-speed-as-a-bullet-dropped-from-the-same-hight-by-hand) is relevant.

You say in the comments:

> I tried it and they both hit the ground on the same time. But, how does a bullet from a gun take so long to fall down

It needs an accurate timing detection for the small resistance of the air to make a measurable difference.

Comment: @safesphere I should qualify it I guess , thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a first approximation, we ignore all forces on the balls except for a uniform gravity in $\hat y$ direction.

Then the time it takes for both balls is same. Infact its same for any two objects. This is since this time is determined solely by vertical motion. Since the initial conditions in the $\hat y$ direction are same and so is the force that acts on them, the resulting time is same too.

The horizontal initial velocity only affects motion in $\hat x$ direction.

This way of separately analyzing horizontal motion by forces and conditioons in the horizontal direction and similarly for those in the vertical direction is allowed by the principle of superposition and that these directions are independent of each other.

Note that horizontal velocity imparted only determines the range. A bullet therefore, does fall to the ground in the same time-its just that it would do so far, far away.

---

If air resistance is included, then too one expects the time to be same as long as the aerodynamics of the two objects are same. The drag only reduces the range. Note that the time of flight  would be larger than before though.

Comment: The part about air resistance is wrong.

Comment: @lalala assuming $\vec{a}_{drag}=-k \,\vec{v}$,for both balls,$\ddot{y}-g-k \,\dot y=0, y(0)=y_0,\dot y(0)=0$ which will lead to the same tof

Comment: @lalala Can you elaborate on why you think it is wrong?

Comment: @safesphere well the model wasnt specified. Generally higher order friction cannot be neglegtect.

Comment: *A bullet therefore, does fall to the ground in the same time-its just that it would do so far, far away.* Do you mean in a galaxy far, far away? A bullet fired horizontally takes a longer time to travel to the Earth than a dropped bullet.

Comment: @Pagoda uniform $g$..ignoring earth's curvature